# Getting WA(Wrong asnwer) for http://www.spoj.com/problems/IITWPC4I/

Tags: java

I have used disjoint set concept to solve this problem. Starting with all milkmen as visited, whenever a new person can be reached with new branch, he is marked as visited. I have already tested following edge cases:

1. There is no milkmen in the city
2. Everyone is milkman
3. Some milkman is not connected to anyone
4. Some person is not connected to anyone
5. Multiple paths between 2 people
6. Milkmen and people are forming disjoint set

Still i am getting WA. Any idea about missing case?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Created by VIVEK VERMA on 9/25/2016.
 */
public class SpojIITWPC4I {
    public static void main(String[] arge) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int T = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            int n = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            int m = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            int totalIncludedNodes = 0;
            ManNode[] people = new ManNode[n];
            Queue<ManLink> links = new PriorityQueue<>();
            tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                int val=Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                people[i] = new ManNode(i);
                if(val==1){
                    people[i].isIncluded = true;
                    totalIncludedNodes++;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<m;i++){
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
                int start = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) -1;
                int destination = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()) -1;
                int value = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                ManLink link = new ManLink(people[start], people[destination], value);
                people[start].AddChild(link);
                people[destination].AddChild(link);
                if(people[start].isIncluded ^ people[destination].isIncluded){
                    links.add(link);
                }
            }

            int minCost = 0;
            while(!links.isEmpty() && totalIncludedNodes <n){
                ManLink link = links.poll();
                ManNode nextAddedNode = (link.source.isIncluded==true?link.destinationNode:link.source);
                if(nextAddedNode.isIncluded){
                    continue;
                }
                minCost += link.value;
                nextAddedNode.isIncluded = true;
                totalIncludedNodes++;
                for(int i=0;i<nextAddedNode.children.size();i++){
                    if((nextAddedNode.isIncluded ^ nextAddedNode.children.get(i).source.isIncluded)
                            || (nextAddedNode.isIncluded ^ nextAddedNode.children.get(i).destinationNode.isIncluded)){
                        links.add(nextAddedNode.children.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            if(totalIncludedNodes == n){
                System.out.println(minCost);
            }else{
                System.out.println("impossible");
            }
        }
    }
}


class ManNode{
    boolean isIncluded = false;
    List<ManLink> children = new ArrayList<>();
    int index;

    ManNode(int index){
        this.index = index;
    }

    void AddChild(ManLink link){
        children.add(link);
    }
}

class ManLink implements Comparable{
    ManNode destinationNode, source;
    int value;
    ManLink(ManNode source, ManNode node, int value){
        this.source = source;
        this.destinationNode = node;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return this.value - ((ManLink)o).value;
    }
}
```